# Show that $x$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\|T\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $T:H\to H$ be a bounded self-adjoint linear operator. Assume there exists $x\in H$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $|\langle Tx,x\rangle|=\|T\|$.

Show that $x$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\|T\|$.

I want to show that $Tx=\|T\|x$ and I know that $\|Tx\|=|\langle Tx,x\rangle|$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: If $T = - \text{id}$, then there is no eigenvalue $\|T\| = 1$. I believe you have to distinguish between the two cases $\langle Tx, x \rangle = \|T\|$ and $\langle Tx, x \rangle = -\|T\|$. In the first one, you will want to show $Tx = \|T\|x$ and in the second you want to show $T x  = -\|T\|x$. Do this by expanding $\|T x - \|T\| x\|^2$ in the first case and $\|T x + \|T\| x\|^2$ in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{blue}{\text{Matthias Klupsch}}$'s comment expanded into an answer:

Let $\,\lambda=\langle Tx,x\rangle\,$ which is equal to $\,\|T\|\,$ or  $\,-\|T\|$.  It is shown that $\,Tx=\lambda x\,$:
$$\begin{align}\|Tx-\lambda x\|^2 & \:=\:\langle Tx,Tx\rangle -2\lambda\,\langle Tx,x\rangle  + \lambda^2\|x\|^2 \:=\: \|Tx\|^2 - \|T\|^2 \\[1ex]
 & \:\leqslant\:\big(\|T\|\|x\|\big)^2 - \|T\|^2 = 0
\end{align}$$